# Clone app with different package name

Tags: android, namespaces, clone, package

I have searched for an answer to this, and it is probably a beginner question.  I am a beginning android programmer and have created my longest code source to date.  Approximately 550 lines in one activity.

I have built this app as a trial/limited version of a full app that I am creating.  The difference between the two builds are 5 lines of code.

Is there a way to clone the first app with a different package name?  I can copy and paste the source in the workspace, and this creates another source with the same package name.

There has to be a faster way than creating a new project and copying and pasting all the code, recreating all the images and icons.  Or I would think there was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a library project then have your two separate projects both use it.  Here is a reference, this is one of the uses google suggests for a library project http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject

Comment: This is going to save me a lot of time and effort.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed your package in your `manifest` file. No problem to change package name until you changed everywhere it is referred, mainly manifest file.